# Objective C Display WebPage as a subclass of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I am a newbie to Objective C Development, So please bear with me.....

My Situation is as follows.....I wanted to detect the user's lat and lon on `RootViewController` and when the user agrees to that, i wanted to pass those values to a webpage (residing on one of my servers). This webpage does all the backend queries based on the lat an lon values passed in to it.....

Does anyone knows how to accomplish this?

---

@Matthew,

```
   Thanks for the response. To answer your questions...
```

1) what does this have to do with UITableView?
   I am trying to show the local Montessori info depending on the geo location of the user.
   This info will be displayed in a UITableView subclass.

2)  And what is supposed to be displayed after the server does the backend queries?
    Well, i guess i tried to answer it in question 1.

Please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: To better understand, please add some information to your question: what does this have to do with UITableView? And what is supposed to be displayed after the server does the backend queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the user's location using the [CoreLocation framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html).

I suggest you start by reading the overview document:

- [Making your Application Location-Aware](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Basically you create a `CLLocationManager` in your controller, and register it as the delegate.  You will receive callbacks with location information, which you can filter and process.  To upload the data to your server, you could use various means such as the [`NSURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) support.